# Keras model with TensorFlow TFRecord Dataset error -- rank is undefined

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tfrecord

I'm using a fairly standard TFRecord dataset. The records are Example protobufs. The "image" feature is a 28 by 28 tensor serialised by `tf.io.serialize_tensor`.

```
feature_description = {
    "image": tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
    "label": tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64)}

image_shape = (28, 28)

def preprocess(example):
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, feature_description)
    image, label = example["image"], example["label"]
    image = tf.io.parse_tensor(image, out_type=tf.float64)
    return image, label

batch_size = 32
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("data/train.tfrecord")\
                 .map(preprocess).batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
```

However, I have the following simple Keras model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=image_shape))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="sgd", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

and whenever I try to fit or predict this model with the dataset

```
model.fit(dataset)
model.predict(dataset)
```

I get the following error:

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.`

Strangely, if I instead create an equivalent dataset via `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images)`, although it yields exactly the same items, the error does not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model needs to infer a single input shape. But `preprocess` parses serialised image tensors of any shape, and this is done on the fly as records are streamed, so it is not possible to infer an input shape for all of the data.

This is easily fixed by adding a TF function which asserts the tensor shape, `tf.ensure_shape`:

```
def preprocess(example):
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, feature_description)
    image, label = example["image"], example["label"]
    image = tf.io.parse_tensor(image, out_type=tf.float64)
    image = tf.ensure_shape(image, image_shape)    # THE FIX
    return image, label
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me. For my use case though i'd prefer to not have to hardcode the shape in my code. I will probably write something to infer it from the files. Do you know of any prebuilt tensorflow way of doing? Or is this just not advised?